# Transpose formula to find a value

Tags: derivatives

Can someone help with this please?

Ive differentiated a formula to get a value, now I need to find the positive value for t for when $\frac{dR}{dt} = 0$

So:

$0 = (27t^{0.5}    e^{-3t}) + (-54t^{1.5} e^{-3t})$

How would go about finding t here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor:
$$0 = (27t^{0.5}    e^{-3t}) + (-54t^{1.5} e^{-3t})
=27\sqrt{t}e^{-3t}\left(1-2t\right) $$
so $t=0$ or $t=1/2$.  If you are looking for strictly positive values then $t=1/2$.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for 0.5, can you explain what you did there please? I dont see where the (1-2t) came from

Comment: Ahh i see it, so then you solve for each of the factors to get two different answers... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can divide out $27t^{0.5}e^{-3t}$ and be left with a linear equation.

Comment: Would that leave, $0 = -54t^{1.5} e^{-3t} + 1$?